# Why webpack chunks load is ignored devServer port?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-dev-server, webpack-4

I'am trying to use dynamic import with React.lazy. Code is quite simple

```
import React, { Component, Suspense, lazy, } from 'react';

const BlazyComponent = lazy(() => {

    return import('./blazy');
});

class Main extends Component {

    render () {

        return (<Suspense fallback={<div>Loading...</div>}>
            <BlazyComponent/>
        </Suspense>);
    }
}

export default Main;
```

So, when I'am starting Webpack devServer, browser console show an error

```
index.js:114 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Loading chunk 0 failed.
(missing: http://domain/build/0.js)
    at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptComplete (index.js:114)
```

As I can see, `index.css` and `index.js` bundles are successfully loaded from `http://domain:8080/build/test/index.css` and `http://domain:8080/build/test/index.js`.

But chunk loads from `http://domain/build/0.js` (webpack devServer ignores port). How can I force chunk load from `http://domain:8080/build/0.js`.

Webpack config

```
entry: {

    'test/index': [ 'babel-polyfill', './resources/assets/modules/test/index', ],
},
output: {

    path: path.resolve(__dirname, './public/build/'),
    publicPath: '/build/',
    filename: '[name].js',
    chunkFilename: '[name].js',
},
...
devServer: {

    host: 'domain',
    port: 8080,
},
```

PS. I know, that I can use environment variables, but searching more elegant decision

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your `publicPath` to `http://domain:8080/build/`?

See https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/#environment-based

Comment: Ok, this works fine, but needs control `publicPath` with environment variables for development and production. So, I think there is more elegant decision ;)

Comment: I updated my answer. You can using a basic env `ASSET_PATH`, or via `__webpack_public_path__`.